# how to write Mono<FilePart> to OutputStream in webflux?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I have such code

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.mono


 @PostMapping("/upload", consumes = ["multipart/form-data"])
    suspend fun uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") file: Mono<FilePart>,
                           @RequestPart("path") path: String): Mono<Void> = coroutineScope {

        val filepart = file.awaitSingle()
        val remotepath = path.urljoin(filepart.filename())
        logger.info("remotepath: $remotepath")

        val sambafile = sambaUtils.file(remotepath)
        val outputStream = sambafile.outputStream

        filepart.content().doOnEach {
            mono {
                logger.info("enter here")
                val databuffer = it.get()!!
                val inputStream = databuffer.asInputStream()

                val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
                var n = inputStream.read(buffer)
                logger.info("write $n bytes")

                while (n != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, n)
                    n = inputStream.read(buffer)

                    logger.info("write $n bytes")
                }

                outputStream.flush()
                outputStream.close()
                inputStream.close()
            }
        }.then()
    }
```

given a Mono and OutputStream, I want to write the content of Mono into OutputStream

as you can see, I add some logs and the log is
[image]

the application does not enter the `mono` scope

so I modify my code to this one

```kotlin
        filepart.content().doOnEach {
            logger.info("enter here")
            val databuffer = it.get()!!
            val inputStream = databuffer.asInputStream()

            val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
            var n = inputStream.read(buffer)
            logger.info("write $n bytes")

            while (n != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, n)
                n = inputStream.read(buffer)

                logger.info("write $n bytes")
            }

            outputStream.flush()
            outputStream.close()
            inputStream.close()

        }.then()
```

but there are warnings: **Possibly blocking call in non-blocking context could lead to thread starvation**
they are in the io opeartions, such like `write`, `read`, `flush` and so on.

so what is the correct code ?

---

update
oh, shit. I found that this code can fix it

```kotlin
@PostMapping("/upload", consumes = ["multipart/form-data"])
    suspend fun uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") file: Mono<FilePart>,
                           @RequestPart("path") path: String): Mono<Void> = coroutineScope {

        val filepart = file.awaitSingle()
        val remotepath = path.urljoin(filepart.filename())
        logger.info("remotepath: $remotepath")

        val sambafile = sambaUtils.file(remotepath)
        val outputStream = sambafile.outputStream

        DataBufferUtils.write(filepart.content(), outputStream).then()
    }
```

just use `DataBufferUtils.write` is ok, but I found that
[image]

there is error in IDEA, but it is ok to compile it, wtf ?

[image]

can anyone tell me what is the wrong with my IDEA ?